# How do I filter csv email attachments via RouteonAttributes by attachment name?

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to filter csv email attachments I extract from gmail via `ConsumeIMAP` by their file name. I am having trouble with what syntax to use when I am configuring `RouteonAttributes` processor.

I was able to extract the csv file from gmail by configuring RouteonAttributes to

```
fetchcsv | ${filename:contains('.csv')}
```

but when I try to specify the filename

```
"${filename:contains('Threat_-_SQL_Injection_-_Rule*')}"
```

it always routes to unmatched. The file name is `Threat_-_SQL_Injection_-_Rule-2019-06-29`. The date following `"Rule-"` will be constantly changing as well depending on the date it was sent. I would also need to write a route to property name for the file `"Threat_-_Vulnerability_Scanner_-_Rule-2019-06-28"`. Any help with the configuration would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler solution would be to use

```
"${filename:contains('Threat_-_SQL_Injection_-_Rule*')}"
```

like you did earlier but drop the "*"

```
"${filename:contains('Threat_-_SQL_Injection_-_Rule')}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `startsWith` instead of `contains` as -

```
 ${filename:startsWith('Threat_-_SQL_Injection_-_Rule')}
```

[image]

This will match for any file that starts with "Threat_-_SQL_Injection_-_Rule" string. This means, date part on your file can vary.You can refer to [Apache Nifi Expression Language guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) for more details